# How to force a compilation error if a raw type is used in Java, to enforce generic type argument?

Tags: java, generics

I have a very simple Java class :

```
public abstract class Hash {
    protected byte[] hash;

    public Hash() {
        hash = new byte[32];
    }
}
```

And an implementation:

```
public class Sha1 extends Hash {
    public Sha1() {
        super();
    }
}
```

And a very simple generic:

```
public class Block<T extends Hash> implements Serializable {

    private T hash;

    public Block() {
    }
}
```

Now in some other code, for some reason I can create a `Block` like the following:

```
Block block = new Block();
```

instead of:

```
Block<Sha1> block = new Block<>();
```

The code should not compile.  Why am I seeing this?

**EDIT**

How can I avoid the creation of Raw Types and enforce the user to give a parameter on instantiation?

Comment: You mean _instead of `Block<Sha1> block = new Block<>();`_, right?

Comment: That is why we use Generics, to get exception at compiletime

Comment: Yeah, that's what I mean.  And yes, I am trying to get an exception at compile time, I am wondering why I am not.

Comment: If you use Eclipse, go to Preferences - Compiler - Errors/Warnings - Generic types and flag 'Usage of a raw type' as an error.